# Overflow error when using C++ std::cin, has strange value inside variable (C++11)

Tags: c++, cin

For a C++ program, I've implemented 2 functions:

1. Make1DArray that takes array size as input and creates a 1D array of that size
2. Make2DArray that takes size of row and column and creates a 2D array of the given row and column sizes

The main function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "enter 1d array length: ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    Make1DArray(x);

    cout << "enter 2d array row size: ";
    int nrows, ncols;
    cin >> nrows;
    cout << "enter 2d array col size: ";
    cin >> ncols;
    Make2DArray(nrows, ncols);

    return 0;
}
```

When I input x = 10000000000 (10^10), the program outputs does not run the second function and asks for input. The message outputs look like this:

```
enter 1d array length: 100000000000
enter 2d array row size: enter 2d array col size:
```

So I checked the values for x, nrow, and ncol and the values were this:

- x = 2147483647
- nrows = 0
- ncols = 32767

I googled a bit and found out that when an overflow error happens, cin would assign x the closest value.
For nrows I understand it might get 0, as an error happened.

What I don't get is why the third variable, ncols is assigned value 32767. I did find out that 32767 is the max value of a short int but I don't know why the variable ncols would get this value.

Could anyone explain me this? Thanks!

ETA: I wasn't sure if I should add the two functions because they're really simple but just in case, they look like this:

```
void Make1DArray(int arrSize) {
    int *arr;
    arr = (int *)malloc(arrSize * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
}

void Make2DArray(int nrows, int ncols) {
    int **arr = (int **)malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(ncols * sizeof(int));
    int count;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = ++count;
        }
}
```

Comment: In the good ol' days when  `cin >> ncols;` failed to read it would not change the value of `ncols` and since `ncols` has not been initialized, you gets what you gets and can't count on rhyme or reason. Now why has `ncols` failed...?

Comment: Which version of C++? As user4581301 indicates the rules for this changed with C++11 (I think).

Comment: I'm using C++11! I think that's why x is given the max value of int. I'll add this into the question. Thanks!

Comment: When in C++ reserve `malloc` for really weird edge cases and when you're building low-level building blocks for other programs. Prefer to use `new`  because it does a lot more for you and is harder to screw up. That said, prefer a library container like `std::vector` to `new`.

Comment: General suggestion: Every time you perform an IO transaction, test the stream before you to anything that assumes the transaction worked. Something like `if (cin >> x) { use x } else { clean up stream }`.

Comment: The cin stream will enter a failed state after the first failed read and needs to be reset before reading further values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

THe problem is that the first overflow sets the failbit due to the value overflow.  The subsequent readings are not performed, leaving `nrows` and `ncols` in an undefined state. If you'd initialize theses variables, you'll notice that they wouldn't change.

### Solution

1. Do not use `int` for holding the size but `size_t` instead.  This should work with your example figures on most compilers.
2. If you want your code to be bullet proof, check the state on `cin` to see if input was valid and handle any errors if necessary (including `cin.clear()` to clear the fail state before resuming reading).
3. Not related: in the code of your functions (which leak memory by the way), iterate on a `size_t` as well.  And avoid  `malloc()`: in C++ prefer  `new` for dynamically creating objects.